# Error in Image Cropper using registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, kotlin, image-cropper

I am using Canhub Cropper library to crop image in my android project. However, I am finding a strange issue in the implementation. First of all here is my code to launch the cropper:

```
import com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView
import com.canhub.cropper.CropImageContract

private var croplauncher = registerForActivityResult(CropImageContract()) { result ->
       if (result.isSuccessful) {
           // Use the returned uri.
           val uriContent = result.uriContent
           val uriFilePath = result.getUriFilePath(this@Doctor) // optional usage
//Do More Here
       } else {
           // An error occurred.
           val exception = result.error
       }
   }

private fun cropImage() {
       croplauncher.launch(
           options {
               setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
           }
       )
   }
```

Here in this code android studio throws an error Unresolved Reference: options in cropImage function

Stuck with this for long. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think these are a missing function or just the library doc was out of date. But you can change your `cropImage`  like this

```
private fun cropImage() {
    // Start picker to get image for cropping and then use the image in cropping activity.
    cropImage.launch(
        CropImageContractOptions(uri = "YOUR URI", cropImageOptions = CropImageOptions(
            guidelines = CropImageView.Guidelines.ON
        ))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use following complete code

Add implementation in gradle file

```
//Image Cropping Lib
    implementation("com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0")
```

Register Activity for Result

```
var cropImage = registerForActivityResult<CropImageContractOptions, CropImageView.CropResult>(CropImageContract(),
            ActivityResultCallback<CropImageView.CropResult> { result: CropImageView.CropResult ->
                if (result.isSuccessful) {
                    val cropped = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(result.getUriFilePath(applicationContext, true))
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(cropped)
                  }
            })
```

Launch code - Using cropImageContractOptions and CropImageOptions, Pass uri you are looking for (If not working try this  "var uri: Uri ?= null" )

```
var cropImageContractOptions = CropImageContractOptions(uri,CropImageOptions(imageSourceIncludeGallery = false,imageSourceIncludeCamera= true));
            cropImage.launch(cropImageContractOptions);
```

Also don't forget to add this CropImageActivity in the Manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name="com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"
            />
```